# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium

I have for the first time tired using Selenium to check login to one application.
Everything has been working fine when I am trying on my local.

But when I deploy it my server, it throws the below error:

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1076
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 862
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 893
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByName(String name) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 595
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__8(ISearchContext context) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\By.cs:line 144
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\By.cs:line 309
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 330

Selenium version: 2.42
IE version: 11
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

I have already Enabled Protected mode for four zones. 
Also disabled Enhanced Protected Mode under Advanced tab.

I do see there is one post for making registry changes but being company server, I am uncomfortable doing that.
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration...there%27s

The weird part is that the same code is working on my local but not when I deploy it.

Also I have tried using both 32 bit and 64 bit IE.

I have also included IEDriverServer path in the Path Environment Variables.

Also tried using Wait method but even if I increase it to 10 minutes, it still gets timed out.

So I am kind of exhausted with options since I seem to have tried most of the things but all in vain. If you believe if I left anything, please help me direct towards it and I will be more than happy to try that.

Also as pat of requirement, I need to use IE 11 only.

I am getting the error at line:
 IWebElement userNameTxt = driver.FindElement(By.Name("USER"));

Below is the code:

```
                string IE_DRIVER_PATH = AppSetting.Get("Driver Path");
                var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();

                IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, options);

                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

                try
                {

                    driver.Url = url;
                    IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60.00));
                    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Name("USER")));

                    IWebElement userNameTxt = driver.FindElement(By.Name("USER"));
                    IWebElement passwordTxt = driver.FindElement(By.Name("PASSWORD"));

                    userNameTxt.SendKeys(username);
                    passwordTxt.SendKeys(password);

                    IWebElement loginBtn = driver.FindElement(By.Name("LOGIN"));
                    loginBtn.Click();


                    IWebElement afterLoginWait = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
                    {
                        return d.FindElement(By.Id("navigation"));
                    });

                    IWebElement logoutTxt = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href='/Session/Logout']"));
                    logoutTxt.Click();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logging.AppendLogData("Failure logging to : " + url + ".", ex);
                    emailMessage.AppendLine("Issue in accessing : " + url + ".</tr>");
                }

                finally
                {
                    driver.Close();
                    driver.Dispose();
                }
```

Comment: So start looking at the differences between your local machine and the server. One thing that spreads to my mind: how are the tests run locally vs on the server, does that differ?

Comment: Thanks Arran. Basically I needed to test the login every few minutes and if any issue, we should be notified. So sort of monitoring tool. In my local, I test this using Unit Test while in the server, I deploy the dll and it runs as a windows service. Also I think there is some issue when I try to run it was windows service. I deployed the service to my local as well and it threw the same error. But still not sure why it doesnt run when used in windows service.

Comment: Does the windows service run under a particular user? I know there can be issues if the user it's logged under doesn't have an interactive desktop session.

Comment: Yeah it runs under a service account and let me check if it has interactive desktop session. Good point Arran. I will shortly let you know my findings.

Comment: @Aaran.. I was able to launch IE after selecting Local System account and checking Allow service to interact with Desktop but then issue is we get the pop up after this and I need to select View the Message and after that I can see the browser with the intended URL but unfortunately it seems to be crashing. I disabled Interactive Services Detection to get rid of pop up but again I get the same issue as earlier "Unable to find window element." Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ultimately the IEDriver simply isn't supported under a Windows Service: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Running_IEDriverServer.exe_Under_a_Windows_Service  ....so I'd doubt you'd ever get this to work, at least not in a reliable and stable fashion. However I'd take it out of a Windows Service and launch it manually on the server - do you get the same thing? Also you should do that registry setting, it again, is the only supported way of running IE11 with Selenium. No point running around until you've tried it.

Comment: Understood. I think I will need to figure out some other way to have this requirement implemented in windows service. Thanks for all your help Arran!!